# "Marshall" or "Marshal"? "Marshalling" or "Marshaling"?

Tags: terminology, marshalling

Which one is it in a programming context?  Is there a difference?  I've seen it both ways and I don't want to spell it wrong in my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Marshal (one l) is correct in English. However, both Marshalling or Marshaling are correct.

Marshalling (with two lls) "seems to make more sense" in my American-English mind as it softens the "a" explicitly.

**Some Links**

- Free Dictionary - [marshal](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/marshal)
- Merriam Webster - [marshal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marshal) & [marshalling](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marshalling)
- Google Trends - [marshalling vs marshaling](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=marshalling,marshaling)

Comment: So it's a po-tay-toh, po-tah-toh kind of thing.

Comment: doesn't count, I'm talking about real folks :)

Comment: lol at the googlefight link.  Thanks for the input.  I think I like "marshal" and "marshalling", and it seems to be the choice the JDK authors made, so I'll go with it.

Answer (score 3):

[Marshal, marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with ["Marshal"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and ["Marshalling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 2):

marshal is the job tile; such as, Fire Marshal or US Marshal, Field Marshal

marshal is the verb as "to gather" your forces, thoughts, facts, etc.
British double the LLs for marshalled, lling.

Marshall is a person's name, 1st or last.